# ¿Como puedo ocultar un query string de la url?

Tags: .htaccess

Lo quiero es ocultar los query strings de la url, osea saber si la url tiene el query y solo obtener el valor del query.

Digamos esta es mi url:

```
http://miurl.com/?query=valor
```

Y quiero que sea modificada de esta forma:

```
http://miurl.com/valor
```

Pero que no permita de ningún modo la url tenga el query como en el primer ejemplo. Osea a lo que me refiero es crear urls amigables, y que si se detecta un query en la url automáticamente lo redirija a la url con solo el valor del query.

Digamos que escribimos la url asi:

```
http://miurl.com/?query=valor
```

Y redirigir a:

```
http://miurl.com/valor
```

Ahora la pregunta es, como puedo lograrlo con htaccess?

Mi archivo htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?query=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Busca en Google «redirección 301 htaccess» y prueba alguna de las soluciones que encuentres. Si te aparece un error o el funcionamiento no es el esperado, puedes [edit] esta pregunta siguiendo la guía [mcve].

Comment: Ya lo intente y lo único que hace es crearme un redirección infinita.

Comment: Publica tu archivo `.htaccess` eliminando las partes sensibles. Usa esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es lo que necesitas

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html?query=$1 [R=301,L]
```

- En la primera línea `RewriteEngine On` activas las redirecciones.
- Omito las dos líneas siguientes porque no las necesitas para tu problema, pero tu **debes considerarlas** si tienes otros usos.
- La última línea hace la redirección `RewriteRule ^(.*) /?query=$1 [R=301,L]`

  - Primero indica que es una regla de reescritura `RewriteRule`
  - A continuación, `^(.)` captura (o hace *match*) todos los caracteres desde el inicio
  - Esta parte `/?query=$1` es la que se manda al servidor. El resultado capturado, se anexa a la cadena `/?query=`
  - La bandera `R=301` indica que la página se movió de [forma permanente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)
  - La bandera `L` indica que es la [última regla](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) y que **no deben** procesarse otras, si las hubiera.

> En tu caso, solo reemplaza la última línea.

Comment: Oh ya entiendo, pero quiero saber si con eso se puedo lograr lo que yo quiero. Por ejemplo si se escribe la url con `?query=xvalor` en la barra de direcciones, automáticamente elimina la parte `?query=` y solo deja `xvalor`, o no?

Comment: ¿Ya lo intentaste?

Comment: Pues si pero no redirecciona y solo crea un bucle de redirección infinita

Comment: Osea no obtiene el valor del query y me añade mas valores, digamos hace esto ?query=valor?query=valor?query=valor, no hace un correcta redirección.

Comment: Vale. Una pregunta mas: ¿qué archivo procesa tu query, cómo se llama, `índex.php` o algo así?

Comment: Lo procesa `index.html` configure mi htaccess para que los archivos html puedan ser leidos como PHP.

Comment: Ok. Edité mi respuesta para indicar con precisión cual es el archivo que procesa las consultas. Y asegúrate que otras partes de tu archivo htacces no estén causando tu error.

Comment: De echo la primeras 3 directivas que indexaste las tengo añadidas a mi htaccess.  No entiendo que sucede. Pero bueno gracias, te agradezco mucho tu paciencia. Una pregunta mas, he visto que algunas paginas en sus archivos css y js, les tienen añadido el favicon de la pagina. Y me gustaría saber como lograr eso? xD espero no aprovecharme de tu paciencia. Y sino aun así te lo agradezco mucho. :D

Comment: Si ya terminamos con esta pregunta hay dos opciones: la cerramos porque no es un problema que no se puede reproducir o la marcas como aceptada. Y si tienes otra pregunta, abre otro tema, siguiendo la guía que te he comentado al principio.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias.